# How can I get class files from Maven dependency into the target\classes folder

Tags: java, maven, .class-file

Is there any sort of Maven plugin that allows me to copy the class files for a dependency into the target\classes folder for my project? Currently I have to manually open the jar file that has the dependencies extract the package that I need to copy over and then copy it into the target\class folder for my project.

I need a way to do those ideally within the pom.xml file but I haven't been able to find a solution that works. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: try maven clean install command

Comment: Why do you like to copy the classes of a dependency into `target/classes` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise need to copy the classes of dependency because the application this project is for (Creo) needs the class folder with dependencies all in one place to work properly

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a terrible idea. If you want to include unpacked dependencies into your project, use the maven assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven-dependency-plugin. [Here is an example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) of how you can extract the content of a dependency JAR:

```
    <project>
       [...]
       <build>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.1.2</version>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                 <id>unpack</id>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>unpack</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                   <artifactItems>
                     <artifactItem>
                       <groupId>junit</groupId>
                       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                       <version>3.8.1</version>
                       <type>jar</type>
                       <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                       <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                       <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
                       <excludes>**/*test.class</excludes>
                     </artifactItem>
                   </artifactItems>
                   <includes>**/*.java</includes>
                   <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
                   <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                   <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                 </configuration>
               </execution>
             </executions>
           </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </build>
       [...]
     </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the example to use of assembly pulgin and it works for me

below is the child pom plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>my parent package statup class</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Parent pom plugin

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```